# In CLion, how do you set CMakeLists.txt option values?

Tags: cmake, clion, buildconfiguration, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to use CLion (latest version - 2019.3) to work on a source repository of mine, which already uses CMake (i.e. has a `CMakeLists.txt`). Now, the package has some options regarding which targets to build; by default it builds just a few, but if you set an option to `ON`, then a bunch of tests are compiled and built.

Unfortunately, I don't quite see where CLion lets you set CMake option values for the build subdirectories it generates. Is it really forcing the defaults on you, or am I missing something in the main UI or the preferences?

Comment: What is wrong in adding `-D` options in [CMake options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html) field?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I suppose that could work, if I force a re-configuration.

Comment: CLion will reconfigure project automatically as soon you change any of cmake related options

Comment: I am also very interested in this. Very frustrating that I have to change CMakeLists.txt to enable one or other option. Even worse: you have to additionally "reset cache and reload project" every time you set option ON/OFF.

Comment: @a_girl: See my answer.

Comment: @einpoklum It appears you are the originator of the [cmakelists-options] tag. [A meta has been opened to burninate the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398108/what-is-the-tag-cmakelists-options-about). You might want to weigh in if you want to keep it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### CLion 2022.2 and later

CMake now supports setting (cached) option values:

1. On the Menu, choose File | Settings...
2. In the navigation tree, locate Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake
3. In the Profiles pane, choose the CMake profile for which you want to edit options.
4. You will see an expandable area entitled "Cache Variables".

[image]

#### CMake 2022.1 and earlier

For now, there's no UI for setting option values. You'll need to edit your CMake profiles (on the menu: File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake) and manually add CMake command-line options, e.g. `-DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=ON`.

I've filed bug [CPP-20268](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-20268) about this fact.

CLion developers are planning to allow this through a mechanism for editing all of the CMake cache - an approach which I disapprove of, but it'll be better than nothing I suppose. That is issue [CPP-423](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-423).